# Recursive Function not Resolving with Conditional and SetTimeout

Tags: javascript, recursion

### **Challenge Description**

Unsuccessful attempts at implementing a snippet that includes a recursive function with setTimeout and a promise. Recursion and setTimeout works, but the promise doesn't seem to be resolving as here is no message output in the *thenable* configured in projectMGR().

### Solution Attempts

Extensively review of execution context, the various methods of promise resolving , exercises on MDN  and review of solutions on stack overflow have proven unsuccessful. Additionally, attempts have been made at wrapping the call to the recursive function in an async (as it is currently configured), also configuring the the promise directly in the  GEC.

### stack overflow References

[Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51872491/promise-not-resolving-from-recursive-function-with-settimeout)
[Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298523/recursive-function-not-returning)
[Solution 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8298523/recursive-function-not-returning)

Any comments or assistance greatly appreciated.

---

| Expected Output | Actual Output |
| --- | --- |
| 10 more to go... | 10 more to go... |
| 9 more to go... | 9 more to go... |
| 8 more to go... | 8 more to go... |
| 7 more to go... | 7 more to go... |
| 6 more to go... | 6 more to go... |
| 5 more to go... | 5 more to go... |
| 4 more to go... | 4 more to go.. |
| 3 more to go... | 3 more to go... |
| 2 more to go... | 2 more to go... |
| 1 more to go... | 1 more to go... |
| Finished just in time for Happy Hour!. |  |

```
projectMGR();
const prom = [];


async function recursiveInterval(arr, n, ms = 1000) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout (() =>
            {   
                if (n === 0) {
                    resolve(`Finished just in time for Happy Hour!. `)
                } else {
                    console.log(`${n} more to go...`);
                    recursiveInterval(arr, n - 1) - arr[n - 1];
                };
            },ms);
        }
    );
};


async function projectMGR() {
    let arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
    let n = arr.length;
    new Promise(() => {
        recursiveInterval(arr, n)
            .then((resolve) => console.log(resolve))
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you @tincot. This was my first question and when I got the error message I wasn't sure how to fix it. I tried to use the code block but obviously it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works better. And also always remember to use functions or variables AFTER you have defined them.

```js
async function recursiveInterval(arr, n, ms = 1000) {
  if (n === 0) {
    return 'Finished just in time for Happy Hour!.';
  } else {
    console.log(`${n} more to go...`);
    await new Promise(res => { setTimeout(res, ms); });
    const t = await recursiveInterval(arr, n - 1);
    return t;
  }
};

async function projectMGR() {
    let arr = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
    let n = arr.length;
    await recursiveInterval(arr, n)
      .then((resolve) => console.log(resolve))
}

projectMGR();
```

Comment: AWESOME @djceaser9114, THANK YOU!. As far as the placement of the variables, I wanted them at the top for accessibility and due to hoisting figure it wouldn't be an issue. But you succeed in my preference not to have any global variables at all.  Thanks again for the quick help.